# How to Get CA Configured Certifiers names List in domino server programmatically using c#?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, ca, interop-domino

To register using new user using CA Process option , CA Configured Certifiers Name is required how can i get that programatically ? I was tried reading documents in ($Certifiers) view in names.nsf file but there is no certifier name available.

Comment: Domino certificates are store in Files. Usualy with extension '.kyr'.  
You need to use a tool 'kyrtool.exe' (Must be Domino 9 IF3 or bigger).  

I'm not sure they are there but take a look

Comment: Just to get the certifier names i need use kyrtool.exe ?

Comment: sry.. but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

There's a hidden view $CertificateAuthorities where all the CA enabled certifiers are listed.

Comment: When i am reading $CertificateAuthorities view i have an entry in it with Certifier FullName is  O=Test. But when i try to register a user using CA Configured Certifier option in that the certifier name is like /Test this. Why both the names are differnet ? How can i derive this /Test name from FullName by just adding / and removing 0= ? is this way of deriving is correct ?

Comment: Notes names are hierarchical (like in ldap). There's a special NotesName class available for handling these conversions.